# nested set save to database

Tags: ajax, laravel, nested-sets, jqtree

I'm trying to implement jqTree with Laravel app.

1. Controller gets data and return view:

   ```
   public function index()
   {
       $categories = Category::get(['id', 'name', '_lft', '_rgt', 'parent_id'])->toTree();
       return view('category.index', [
           'categories' => $categories
       ]);
   }
   ```
2. Here is a view (javascript part):

   ```
   var data = {!! $categories !!};

   $('#tree').tree({
           data: data,
           dragAndDrop: true,
           onDragStop: handleMove,
   });

   function handleMove() {
       var treeData = $('#tree').tree('toJson');

   $.ajax({
       url: 'category',
       type: 'POST',
       headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
       data: { data: treeData },
   });


   }
   ```
3. This builds tree properly and I can drag & drop items. However, I want to save reordered tree back to database. Here is a post method in a controller:

   ```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
     $data = $request->data;
     $result = Category::rebuildTree($data);
     ...
   }
   ```

After calling rebuildTree method, I'm getting this error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Kalnoy\\Nestedset\\QueryBuilder::rebuildTree() must be of the type array, string given
```

I have tried with this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $data = $request->data;
  $data = json_decode($request->data);
  $array_data = (array) $data;
  $result = Category::rebuildTree($data);
  ...
}
```

This however returns:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

How can I get array of data passed so I can use `rebuildTree()` method and update database?

Here is a result of `dd($request->data):`

```
[{"name":"Storage","id":3,"_lft":17,"_rgt":18,"parent_id":null,"is_open":true,
    "children":[{"name":"Laptops","id":1,"_lft":1,"_rgt":10,"parent_id":null,"is_open":true,
    "children":[{"name":"Monitors","id":2,"_lft":11,"_rgt":16,"parent_id":null,
    "children":[{"name":"IPS","id":5,"_lft":14,"_rgt":15,"parent_id":2}]},
    {"name":"Macbook","id":6,"_lft":2,"_rgt":3,"parent_id":1},
    {"name":"Acer","id":7,"_lft":4,"_rgt":5,"parent_id":1},
    {"name":"New Subcategory Name","id":8,"_lft":6,"_rgt":7,"parent_id":1},
    {"name":"New Subcategory ame","id":9,"_lft":8,"_rgt":9,"parent_id":1}]}]},
    {"name":"Memory","id":4,"_lft":19,"_rgt":20,"parent_id":null}]
```

Also, just to be clear: I'm using [jqTree](https://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/)

Nested set is [lazychaser/laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset)

Comment: Can you show what you get with dd($request->data) in your store method?

Comment: Please check updated post where you can see dd output. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `json` in `$request->data;` you need to decode it in array using `json_decode()` along with second parameter as `true` for assoc

[see the manual](http://www.php.net/json_decode')

> assoc
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative
>   arrays.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $result = Category::rebuildTree(json_decode($request->data,True));
  ...
}
```

and if you need to pass it in `$data` then pass it like this.

```
$data = json_decode($request->data,True);
```

**Alternatively**

```
foreach ($request->data as $value) 
    $array[] = $value->name;
```

then pass this `$array` into your query like this

```
$result = Category::rebuildTree($array);
```

Comment: If I use `$result = Category::rebuildTree($request->data);` then this is an error: _Type error: Argument 1 passed to Kalnoy\Nestedset\QueryBuilder::rebuildTree() must be of the type array, string given_

`$data[] = $request->data;` returns _array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given_

Comment: No, I didn't. However, even if I add them I'm getting the same results. Problem here is that jqTree returns a string instead of array

Comment: make sure you have array here in `var treeData = $('#tree').tree('toJson');` if so then you need to use json_decode() I think you are getting json in `$request->data`  which laravel considering as a string

Comment: Already tried `json_decode()` - check my original post. Thanks :)
Result is `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: oh I missed that ok updated my answer for your `json_decode()` problem

Comment: use with second parameter `true` for getting object in associative array

Comment: Finally! It was so obvious: `json_decode($request->data, TRUE)` returns associative array. The whole time I was missing optional parameter for `json_decode()` :) Thanks !!!